# Delphi SOAP client cannot connect, getting HTML instead of XML for WSDL

Tags: delphi, iis, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP CGI server written in Delphi 10.3.1 and a corresponding client. This has been in production for many years. Yesterday, after installing some Windows updates, the client is no longer able to connect, getting the following error:

> End tag 'head' does not match the start tag 'META'. Line: 22

That is on my localhost, no code change since yesterday when it worked fine. However, I am able to connect my local client to the production server and all of the production clients have no problems, with exactly same code.

So that implies the problem is local to my machine, which is good in a way, but I need to get it to work locally. If I run the local “service info” from a browser, I get the usual listing of functions. But if I click “WSDL” link then nothing happens, but on the real server it gives me a nice XML WSDL file. If I look at the HTML from the service info page, it appears to correspond to the error above, in that there is a `</head>` tag on line 22 and it has a prior `<META>` tag. But that is very weird because the client is not supposed to be looking at the service info page, is it? I have recompiled everything and rebooted a few times, no change.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. *Problem* has no meaning at all. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title conveys no useful information. You should take some time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: HTTP wise the client still connects, as otherwise you wouldn't get a response informing you of some error. Also: how is this Delphi related if you don't list code which reproduces your problem?

Comment: Yes I guess it does, but the server is sending back something the client does not appear to understand. There is no particular code to show - problem appears when client invokes any function in the interface.

Comment: So instead of getting back an WSDL nothing happens? That doesn't seem right. Do you get a 204 status code? Do you get an empty page? Or do you get back an HTML file? What does nothing mean? When you get back the HTML what does the HTML contain?

Comment: What happens is the client invokes a function of the interface and the server  throws an exception with the above message about the head tag. This is not part of my code.

On the Service Info page in browser, clicking the WSDL link just redisplays the interface page, not the XML of the WSDL as expected.

Comment: Capturing the request and response with something like Wireshark could help troubleshoot the calls. Also, this seems like some sort of deployment issue. Is your SOAP service running properly? Do you get errors when starting the server?

Comment: I re-created the website on my localhost, with exactly same settings and now it works but the original site does not. There must be something different, trying to figure that out.